# Django postgres connector psycopg2

Tags: python, django

As i run pip install psycopg2 in my django virtualven in windows it start downloading and at the end of downloading this Error comes

```
  |████████████████████████████████| 430kB 61kB/s
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\tusha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\tusha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hoeubopv\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\tusha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hoeubopv\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\tusha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoeubopv\psycopg2\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\tusha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoeubopv\psycopg2\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating C:\Users\tusha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoeubopv\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\tusha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoeubopv\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\tusha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoeubopv\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\tusha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoeubopv\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\tusha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoeubopv\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPIe install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
                                                               st' file (also at
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).
                                                               egg_info Check the logs for full command outpu
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py 
egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

so how to solve this ERROR

Comment: `If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPIe install the PyPI  'psycopg2-binary' package instead.`  Perhaps you could try this, as suggested in the traceback you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```